# Error: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T' issue while using df.at function in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When i am trying to use df.at fuction without loop it works fine and change the data for a perticular column but it is giving error while using this in a loop.
Code is here.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Height': [5.1, 6.2, 5.1, 5.2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
         'Height': [4.1, 3.4, 7.1, 9.2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
for i in range(int(len(df1))):
    for j in range(int(len(df2))):
        if df1['Name'][i] != df2['Name'][j]:
            continue
        else:
            out = (df1['Height'][i] - df2['Height'][j])
            df3.at[i, 'Height_Comparison'] = out
            break
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was occurring becz of duplicate column names('Name', 'Height') in Data Frame df3 becz of the concat operation. Concat make double entries with same column names ('Name', 'Height') in Data Frame df3 which is creating this problem.
once i changed the column names to Name1, Height1 in df1 and Name2, Heigh2 in df2 the issue got resolved.